# How do I place an ImageView object using coords when a fragment loads?

Tags: android

I'm a bit of a noob to programming.

I am creating an on screen joystick and a slider and am using an ImageView object to represent the position value in relation to another ImageView object.

I need to know the best way to place this ImageView object in the middle of another ImageView object when the fragment loads.  I have a function centerSlider() and would like to run it after the fragment is created but using it with onCreateView does not work.

Where can I call my function?

```js
     //Centers the position marker on the slider graphic
    public void centerSlider() {
      ImageView sliderPosition = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider_position);
      int posXY[] = new int[2];
      rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider).getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
      int centerX = posXY[0] + ((rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider)).getWidth() / 2);
      int centerY = posXY[1] - ((rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider)).getHeight() / 2);
      sliderPosition.setX(centerX - (rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider_position).getWidth() / 2));
      sliderPosition.setY(centerY - (rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider_position).getHeight() / 2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke centerSlider() method in onCreateView(), you won't get View size through view.getWidth() or view.getHeight(), because measuring haven't been finished, their value is 0. You can try this:

```
rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
  int centerX = posXY[0] + ((rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider)).getWidth() / 2);
  int centerY = posXY[1] - ((rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider)).getHeight() / 2);
  sliderPosition.setX(centerX - (rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider_position).getWidth() / 2));
  sliderPosition.setY(centerY - (rootview.findViewById(R.id.iv_slider_position).getHeight() / 2));
});
```

or you can new a Thread in , let it wait more than 300ms, and invoke your method, like this:

```
new Thread(() -> {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(300);
      getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
      centerSlider();
    });
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: I think optimally I need something that creates the object centered then my code can take over with the movement of the object.  Unless there is a layout option that could do this in the xml file?  I tried to use a grid layout to take advantage of the weight option but the grid layout scales past the edge of the screen instead of scaling to the edge of the screen like imageview does.  It's quite frustrating.  Waiting can cause issues if someone has an old slower device.

Comment: Or you can consider to write a custom view for this problem.